# Extracting Number from a Text File in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, winforms

I have written a code for extracting number from a text file using a windows From. Problem is that, Output Occurs in a partial way. Either the First Line is Printing or the Last Line. I want all the line that is containing the number

```
(i.e) If the text file contains,
Auto 2017
Mech 2056
CSE 2016
```

I want only those 2017, 2056, 2016 to be printed.

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string infile = textBox1.Text;
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(infile);
   string allDetails = File.ReadAllText(infile);
   string result = Regex.Match(allDetails, @"\d+").Value;
   richTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way, if you want output `2017,2056,2016`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string infile = textBox1.Text;
     string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(infile);
     string temp = "";
     int i = 0;
     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
         string result = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
         if (i == 0)
         {
            temp = result;
         }
         else
         {
            temp = temp + "," + result;
         }
         i++;
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = temp;
}
```

or if you want single value `2017` `2056` `2016` then

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string infile = textBox1.Text;
     string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(infile);
     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
         string result = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
         richTextBox1.Text = result ;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are try to grab numeric value. Regex.Matches Will help you to solve your problem.

Below is simplified code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {          
    string filedetails = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
    var regexCollection = Regex.Matches(filedetails, @"\d+");
    foreach (Match rc in regexCollection)
       richTextBox1.AppendText(rc.Value + ",");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method. `Regex.Matches`. `Matches` method searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a regular expression.

`Match` method returns the first match only, Subsequent matches need to be retrieved.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string infile = textBox1.Text;
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(infile);
   string allDetails = File.ReadAllText(infile);
   var regexMatchCollection = Regex.Matches(allDetails, @"\d+");
   foreach(Match mc in regexMatchCollection)
   { 
     richTextBox1.AppendText(mc.Value);
     richTextBox1.AppendText(",");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Regex`,below is the simplified code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
   string allDetails = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
   foreach(string word in allDetails.Split(' '))
   {
       int number;
       if(int.TryParse(word, out number))
       {
            numbers.Append(number);
            numbers.Append(",");
       } 
   }
   richTextBox1.Text = numbers.Trim(',');
}
```

Comment: OP didn't want to read the text from text box, also your code will add `,` at the beginning of richTextBox1`

Comment: Updated, textbox1.text has filepath

Answer (score 0):

test.txt has

```
Auto 2017
Mech 2056
CSE 2016
```

in the following program `File.ReadAllLines` will store every line in a `string array` separately.Then we will use `foreach loop` to read single line at a time and store the extracted numbers in list e.g 2017 and finally with `string.Join` we will join the array and separate each word with `","` and save it in string

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
            var textfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test.txt");
            foreach (var line in textfile)
            {
            string result = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
                list.Add(result);
            }
            string numbers = string.Join(",",list.ToArray());
```

the output value will be

```
2017,2056,2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string infile = textBox1.Text;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(infile);
            string allDetails = File.ReadAllText(infile);
            string result = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in Regex.Matches(allDetails, @"\d+"))
            {
                result = result + item.ToString() + ",";
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = result.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\txtFile.txt");
        List<string> Codelst = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            var a= Regex.Match(item, @"\d+").Value;
            Codelst .Add(a);
        }
        var r = Codelst;
    }
```

Output is like this:
[image]